# One div is overlapping another when using polymer

Tags: html, css, polymer

I'm using Polymer to develop my website, and when I use `<core-pages>` and I have my footer, my footer overlapping the `<core-pages>`, I figure the reason is due to the `<core-pages>` having a position of absolute, but if I take the absolute position out it ruins the page. Any suggestions?

Here's is my code

```
<core-pages flex>
        <section id="settings" class="settings">
            <div class="panel">
                <summary style="margin-left:25px">
                    <h1>Account</h1>
                    <p>Here, you can edit your account information</p>
                        <form is="ajax-form" action="ajax.php" method="post">
                            <paper-input-decorator label="Email" floatingLabel>
                                <input is="core-input" name="email" type="email" required="required">
                            </paper-input-decorator>
                            <paper-input-decorator label="Old Password" floatingLabel>
                                <input is="core-input" name="pass" type="password" required="required">
                            </paper-input-decorator>
                            <paper-input-decorator label="New Password" floatingLabel>
                                <input is="core-input" name="newpass" type="password" required="">
                            </paper-input-decorator>
                            <paper-input-decorator label="Confrim New Password" floatingLabel>
                                <input is="core-input" name="newpass" type="password" required="">
                            </paper-input-decorator>
                            <br />
                            <div align="center">
                                <paper-button id="submitButton" raised=""><core-icon icon="arrow-forward"></core-icon>Update My Account</paper-button>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                </summary>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
        asdfsadf
        </section>
    </core-pages>
    <page-footer></page-footer>
```

Here's my page-footer:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="page-footer" noscript>
<template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
        <footer>
            <div>
                <div class="links">
                    <a href="/"><paper-button raised><core-icon icon="archive"></core-icon>Update Archive</paper-button></a>
                    <a href="/"><paper-button><core-icon icon="face-unlock"></core-icon>Contact and Chat</paper-button></a>
                    <a href="/"><paper-button><core-icon icon="account-balance"></core-icon>Legal Disclaimer</paper-button></a>
                    <a href="/"><paper-button><core-icon icon="receipt"></core-icon>Terms of Service</paper-button></a>
                    <a href="/"><paper-button><core-icon icon="bug-report"></core-icon>Report A Bug</paper-button></a>
                </div>
                <p id="copyright">This website and its contents are copyright &copy;2014-2015 Website Name.</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
</template>
</polymer-element>
/**************FOOTER STYLES**************/
footer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    padding: 100px 0;
    padding-left: 64px
}
footer .links {
    margin-bottom: 56px
}
footer paper-button {
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    color: black
}
footer #copyright {
    color: #b3b3b3;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align:center
}
footer>:first-child {
    max-width: 1032px;
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

And the `<core-pages>` css:

```
:host {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}
polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host > *'; }
  ::content > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1000;
}

polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host > .core-selected'; }
     ::content > .core-selected {
     visibility: visible;
     z-index: auto;
}
```

Here are some screenshot of what I'm talking about, to give a better explanation:
With  position absolute: http://prntscr.com/5knveb
Here it is without : http://prntscr.com/5ko78r

Comment: I guess you also do not want the footer to be always visible, but always be underneath your `core-pages`, right? There is a related thread here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279273/core-header-panel-and-sticky-footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279273/core-header-panel-and-sticky-footer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I just had to add a position relative to `polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host > .core-selected'; }
::content > .core-selected {`